# hasOwnProperty not returning correctly?

Tags: javascript

Why is this function returning 'No Contact' instead of 'Akira'?

```js
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
  for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){    
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty.prop){      
      return firstName;      
    }    
    return 'no contact' ;       
  } 
}


var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];





console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
```

Comment: `if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))`

Comment: Because the `hasOwnProperty` function doesn't have a property called `prop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in your `prop` as an argument.

```js
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
  for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){    
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){      
      return firstName;      
    }    
    return 'no contact' ;       
  } 
}


var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];





console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)
```